# Data not displaying based on dates

Tags: sql, date, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I'm a student employee at a university, and I do applications development for our facilities department. We have several in-house applications written in Visual FoxPro (yes I know it's not supported anymore) that I help maintain. Recently we found that one of our tables has an issue filtering by dates. If you look at the table, all of the data displays fine. However if you run a SELECT query against it, looking for all records between a date range, weird things start to happen.

If the start date <= 2014/12/13, and the end date is in 2015 or there is no end date, the result set does not include any records from after 2014/12/13.

If the start date <= 2014/12/14, and the end date is in 2015 or there is no end date, the result set will include the correct records.

This same behavior is exhibited by a view as well as if stand-alone SELECT statements are executed in the command window.

I discovered this morning that if I use the SET FILTER TO command in the command window, I get the correct results.

Has anyone else ever experienced something similar?

Comment: How are you formatting the date in the query?

Comment: which db are you using... is it sql server

Comment: Can you post the actual query?

Comment: It's a foxpro database.
I'm using foxpro's `Date(nYear, nMonth, nDay)` when I test it to match the format of the Date field in the table.

I'm 99% sure the problem is not with the query, but I've been using (basically) `SELECT * FROM Purchreq WHERE Log_date >= Date(2014,12,13)` while I was analyzing it. I've done the WHERE clause many different ways to include an end date and to test different ranges. The actual view for the report uses a slightly different query but the WHERE clause is set up the same.

Comment: I suspect you have a corrupt index. Recreate the tags for this table, or at least the tag on the start date field.

Comment: I was thinking it might be corrupted indexes, it just wasn't the usual corrupt index behavior I'm used to getting. I'll play around with that on Friday and see what I can find.

Comment: Do you have installed SP2?

Comment: Try playing with  ´set strict date´ and do the same query with another table/cursor with the same date, so that can help you if your .dbf is corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tamar suggested, it was most likely a corrupt index. 
Running Validate Database Recover from the command window did not help.
A program that we had previously written for fixing corrupt indexes also did not help, although both reported a successful run.

We took a more aggressive step and deleted the index from the table. This gave us an error about the .DTC file, but the index was gone, and the SELECT worked as expected.

We added the index again, got the same .DCT file error, and the SELECT was back to not working.

At this point we investigated the .DCT file and realized that the last updated date was a week ago, not today, like all of the other files associated with the database.

We used foxpros cleanup database command and then added the index again with no .DCT error and the SELECT worked perfectly.

Thanks for all of your help and suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM Purchreq WHERE Log_date >= CTOD('12/13/2014')
```

Comment: There's no difference.

Comment: The best way to specify an unambiguous date is {^2014-12-13}